# php only modifies last row sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, sql-update

I'm using the following code to modify a sqlite database.

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3("my_sqlite.db");

if( isset($_POST['submit_data']) ){

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $query = "UPDATE students set name='$name', email='$email' WHERE rowid=$id";

    $db->exec($query);
}

$query = "SELECT rowid, * FROM students";
$result = $db->query($query);
?>




        <form action="" method="post">
        <table border="1">

                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                </tr>

            <?php while($data = $result->fetchArray()) {?>
                
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['rowid'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['email'];?>"></td>
                </tr>

            <?php } ?>

        </table>
        <input name="submit_data" type="submit" value="Update Data">
        </form>
```

I've read many related answers but I can't solve the problem, which is, ONLY THE LAST ROW OF THE INPUT WORKS, IT JUST MODIFIES THE LAST ROW OF THE SQLITE.

Comment: you should not skip using prepared queries, enter into name `';--` and your see why

Comment: Wow, as you can see im a beginner. I dont know what prepared queries are but that removed my database :(

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED IT LIKE THIS!!

```
<?php

$db = new SQLite3("my_sqlite.db");

if( isset($_POST['submit_data']) ){

    foreach ($_POST['id'] AS $k => $id) {
        $name = $_POST['name'][$k];
        $email = $_POST['email'][$k];

    $query = "UPDATE students set name='$name', email='$email' WHERE rowid=$id";

    $db->exec($query);
} }

$query = "SELECT rowid, * FROM students";
$result = $db->query($query);
?>




        <form action="" method="post">
        <table border="1">

                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                </tr>

            <?php while($data = $result->fetchArray()) {?>

                <tr>
                    <td><input name="id[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['rowid'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>"></td>
                    <td><input name="email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $data['email'];?>"></td>
                </tr>

            <?php } ?>

        </table>
        <input name="submit_data" type="submit" value="Update Data">
        </form>
```